# Is this the defined behavior?

Tags: c

I have made a macro:

`#define QUEUE_SEND_STATUS(x)    ( (x == 0) ? printf("Fail\n") : printf("Success\n"))`

It works as expected. But, my question is is that is this behavior defined in C? Can function calls be used in MACROS?

Thanks!

Comment: yes. thats what macros are for at times. Although I would simply use a function in such a case.

Comment: You should put `x` within parentheses to make it safer though. Example: `#define QUEUE_SEND_STATUS(x) ((x) == 0 ? printf("Fail\n") : printf("Success\n"))` or simpler `#define QUEUE_SEND_STATUS(x) (puts((x) == 0 ? "Fail" : "Success"))`

Comment: Please create an answer.

Comment: Yes, the preprocessor just replaces your `define` with the statement. You can even do nasty stuff like replace keywords: `#define true false` and `#define private public` (In C++ that would do something).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this code has well-defined behavior. However, there are some ways it could be improved.

- Function-like macro parameters should be surrounded by parenthesis whenever used, to prevent operator precedence bugs: `((x) == 0)`. (The check vs zero is actually superfluous, you could as well just type `(x) ?`)
- You can use the printf calls inside the `?:` operator only because they have the same/compatible return types. In case they were different functions with different return types, it wouldn't be possible.
- The whole thing could be rewritten as:

  `#define QUEUE_SEND_STATUS(x) puts((x) ? "Fail" : "Success")`.